# Show that $\alpha = \inf\{t\,;\,|X_t|>1\}$ is a stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $\{X_t, t \ge 0\}$ be a continuous stochastic process and adapted to the filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t,t\ge 0 \}$ and consider

$$
\alpha = \inf\{t, |X_t|>1\},
$$ 
the first time the the process $X_t$ leaves the interval $[-1,1]$. Then can you help me to show that $\alpha$ is in fact stopping time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Then can you help me to show that $\alpha$ is in fact stopping time?

Well, this would be difficult, since **$\alpha$ is not always a stopping time for the natural filtration $(\mathcal F^X_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ of the process $(X_t)_{t\geqslant0}$**, defined by $\mathcal F^X_t=\sigma(X_s\,;\,0\leqslant s\leqslant t)$.

For a counterexample, consider some event $A$ such that $0<P(A)<1$ and define the process $(X_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ as follows:

- On $A$, $X_t=t$ for every $t\geqslant0$.
- On $\Omega\setminus A$, $X_t=t$ for every $0\leqslant t\leqslant1$ and $X_t=2-t$ for every $t\geqslant1$.

Then $\alpha=\inf\{t\,;\,|X_t|\gt1\}$ equals $\alpha=1$ on $A$ and $\alpha=3$ on $\Omega\setminus A$.

Thus, $\{\alpha\leqslant1\}=A$. For every $t\leqslant1$, the random variable $X_t$ is deterministic, hence $\mathcal F^X_1=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$ is the trivial sigma-algebra, but the event $A$ is not in $\mathcal F^X_1$ hence $\{\alpha\leqslant1\}\notin\mathcal F^X_1$, which proves that $\alpha$ is not a stopping time for the filtration $(\mathcal F^X_t)_{t\geqslant0}$.

Comment: Thanks Did, indeed $\alpha$ is not stopping time in this example.

Comment: @Ilya, thanks I forgot this.

Comment: (+1). It might be worth mentioning that $\alpha$ is a stopping time with respect to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_{t+})_{t \geq 0}$.

Comment: @saz Quite so. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**The proof below is not correct.** See an example by Did. The flaw in the proof: in fact we have
$$
  \{\alpha>t\} = \bigcup_n\{\alpha \geq t+\frac1n\} = \bigcup_{n}\bigcap_{s\in [0,t+\frac1n]}\{|X_s|\leq 1\}
$$
and there appear events $\{|X_s|\leq 1\}$ for $s>t$.

---

By the definition, a random variable $\tau:\Omega\to [0,\infty]$ is a stopping time if and only if
$$
  \{\tau \leq t\}\in \mathscr F_t
$$
for any $t\in [0,\infty)$. We have in your case
$$
  \{\alpha \leq t\} = \Omega\setminus \{\alpha > t\} = \Omega\setminus \bigcap_{s\in [0,t]}\{|X_s|\leq 1\} = \Omega\setminus\bigcap_{s\in \Bbb Q\cap [0,t]}\left\{|X_s|\leq 1\right\} \in \mathscr F_t
$$
where we pass to the intersection over rational numbers only since $X$ has continuous trajectories.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the proof.

Comment: @Shaik: you're welcome

Comment: Is it always true that we pass intersection over rational numbers in your proof? If $\{X_t, t \ge 0\}$ is right continuous, then even in that case do we pass intersection over rational numbers?

Comment: Sorry but the proof does not work since $\{\alpha > t\}$ is not always $$\bigcap_{s\in [0,t]}\{|X_s|\leq 1\}.$$

Comment: @Did: you certainly have a fan :) I'll read your answer now.

Comment: @Did: is that correct then that this even is $\{\alpha\geq t\}$?

Comment: Neither, the most one can say is that the intersection is between $\{\alpha\gt t\}$ and $\{\alpha\geqslant t\}$.

Comment: @Did: can you elaborate on this, please? If $|X_s|\leq 1$ for all $s\leq t$, then $\alpha$ is at least $t$, so the intersection is a subset of $\{\alpha\geq t\}$. Now, if $\alpha\geq t$ suppose there exists $s\leq t$ such that $|X_s|>1$, then by continuity there exists $s'<s\leq t$ such that $|X_{s'}|>1$ and hence $\alpha \leq s' <t$. So, if $\alpha \geq t$ then $|X_s|\leq 1$ for all $s\leq t$. Is there a mistake in this reasoning?

Comment: With continuity, your reasoning is allright. Without continuity, no.

Comment: @Did: I see, we have continuity in the OP, but I'd have to modify 
$$
  \{\alpha>t\} = \bigcup_n\{\alpha \geq t+\frac1n\} = \bigcup_{n}\bigcap_{s\in [0,t+\frac1n]}\{|X_s|\leq 1\}
$$
and there appear events $\{|X_s|\leq 1\}$ for $s>t$.

Comment: Am I confused or someone just upvoted this answer?

Comment: It is me who upvoted. The explantion of $\alpha$ not being stopping time by Ilya seems logical to me.

Comment: @Did I'm not sure what was the purpose of your last question

Comment: I thought the OP already upvoted when they accepted this answer. Note that the explanation added at the beginning of the post points the flaw in the alleged proof that $\alpha$ is a stopping time, not why $\alpha$ is not a stopping time.