# Continuous variable defined over Rational numbers only?

Tags: continuity, rational-numbers

Let $x(t)$ be a solution of some first order ODE, which is continuous over $t$. In this case, is the continuous $x(t)$ defined only over Rational numbers? what is the reason behind this? Please clarify me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your question may need further clarification. However, I guess you are wondering about the following fact. If $x:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous and we know values of $x$ at rational points, then we know $x$ everywhere (just by taking limits thanks to the continuity of $x$).

Comment: I think you have explained me about a stopping time proof in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351984/stopping-time-proof    In that proof, can you kindly explain me the sentence "intersection over rational numbers only since X has continuous trajectories. Thanks to you.

"